# How to fetch data from the database in 2 different tables in Laravel Controller?

Tags: laravel

I don't know how to add $countries to the State queryString below. Could you help me

```
  public function index(){
   // $countries = Country::all();
    $perPage = Requests::input('perPage') ?: 5;
    return Inertia::render('State/Index',[
        'states' => State::query()
        ->when(Requests::input('search'), function($query, $search){
            $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%");
        })
        ->paginate($perPage)
        ->withQueryString(),
        'filters' => Requests::only(['search', 'perPage']),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `$search` variable.

And `->when($condition, function ...)` need a true/false condition.

```
public function index(Request $request){
   // $countries = Country::all();

   // probably best to add validation at this point
   $validated = $request->validate($rules);

   $perPage = $request->input('perPage', 5); // set 5 as default when empty
   $search = $request->input('search');

    return Inertia::render('State/Index',[
        'states' => State::query()
            ->when(!empty($search), function($query, $search){
                $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%");
            })
            ->paginate($perPage)
            ->withQueryString(),
        'filters' => $request->only(['search', 'perPage']),
    ]);
}
```